# Rock, Paper, Scissors Game - Basic Game Simulation

Tags: java, rock-paper-scissors

I enjoyed the many headaches this project gave me as I learned a lot! I have been studying Java for less than a year and am new to programming in general. I read over the comments rules and hope I followed them correctly. I don't know many people that code and would love any feedback. This was a school project I worked very hard on, but I know I have a long way to go. Please, let me know if you can help me get better...

````
import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    public class RPS {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Boolean playAgain = true;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String play;
            
            while (playAgain = true) {      
            WelcomeP1(); //  Welcome & basic rule example
            
            // Final Result & Replay Option
            System.out.print("*********************" );
            System.out.print("-------------> You " +Game()+ "!!!" );
            System.out.println("\n*********************" );
            System.out.println("Play Again?!");
            System.out.println("Please press y for (Y)es or n for (N)o: ");
            play = input.nextLine().trim();
            while (play.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
                System.out.println("Please press y for (Y)es \nor n for (N)o: ");
                play = input
                        .nextLine().trim();
                } // end while ~ validate/catch error ~ for empty space
            switch ( play.charAt(0) ){
                    case 'n' : case 'N':
                        playAgain = false;
                        System.exit(0);
                    case 'y': case 'Y':
                        System.out.println("\n*********************" );
                        System.out.print("Excellent;\nGlad you enjoyed playing!"); 
                        System.out.println("\nJust checking again...");
              } // end while 
            } // end switch 
        } // end main
        
        
            // Welcome Validation Start
            public static void WelcomeP1(){
                Scanner stdIn= new Scanner(System.in);
                Boolean validGame = false;
                String userPlay;
                
                while( validGame == false ){
                System.out.println("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
                System.out.println("Please press y for (Y)es \nor n for (N)o: ");
                userPlay = stdIn.nextLine().trim();
                while (userPlay.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
                    System.out.println("Please press y for (Y)es \nor n for (N)o: ");
                    userPlay = stdIn.nextLine().trim();
                } // end while ~ validate/catch error ~ for empty space
                // below valiates user entry    
                switch ( userPlay.charAt(0) ){
                    case 'n' : case 'N':
                        System.exit(0);
                    case 'y': case 'Y':
                        validGame = true;
                        System.out.println("*************************************");
                        System.out.println("Excellent! Thank you...\nLet's Play!");
                        break;
                    default: 
                } // end switch
            } // end while loop 
            } // end class Welcome ~ End Welcome Validation
            
            
            // User Input Validation Start
            public static int P1Choice(){
                Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
                Boolean validUserIn = false;
                String userInput; 
                int userPiece = 0;
            
                while (validUserIn == false){
                    System.out.println("*************************************");
                    System.out.println("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors ");
                    System.out.println("Please type the first letter only.");
                    System.out.println("Your Choice: ");
                    userInput = userIn.nextLine();
                while (userInput.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors ");
                    System.out.println("Please type the first letter only.");
                    System.out.println("Your Choice: ");
                    userInput = userIn.nextLine();
                } // end while ~ validate/catch error ~ for empty space
                  // below valiates user entry further   
                    userPiece = userInput.charAt(0);
                if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
                    userPiece = 0;
                    System.out.println("You Chose: Rock");
                    validUserIn = true;
                }
                    else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
                        userPiece = 1;
                        System.out.println("You Chose: Paper");
                        validUserIn = true;
                    }
                        else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                            userPiece = 2;
                            System.out.println("You Chose: Scissors");
                            validUserIn = true;
                        }  
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
                            validUserIn = false;
                        } 
                } // end while loop 
            return userPiece;
            } // end class UserPiece ~ End User Input Validation & Return
            
            
            // Computer Choice Calculation & Print ~ Start
            public static int ComputerChoice(){
            Random random = new Random();
            int choiceStart;
            choiceStart = random.nextInt(3); // max number 3 ~ 0-2
            int computerInput = 0;
            String computerPiece = null;
            
            switch (choiceStart) {
                case 0:
                    computerInput = 0; 
                    computerPiece = "Rock";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    computerInput = 1; //Paper
                    computerPiece = "Paper";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    computerInput = 2; //Scissors
                    computerPiece = "Scissors";
                    break;
            } // end switch
            System.out.println("*************************************");
            System.out.println("*************************************");
            System.out.println("The computer has decided as well...");
            System.out.println("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");
            System.out.println("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");
            System.out.println("The computer's choice was " +computerPiece+ "...");
            System.out.println("*************************************");
            System.out.println("*************************************");
            return computerInput;    
            } // end class ComputerChoice ~ End Computer Choice Calculation & Print
            
            
            // Calculate Game & Return Win/Loss/Tie ~ Calculations
            public static String Game(){
                int user = P1Choice();
                int computer = ComputerChoice();
                String error = "*** If you are reading this, there has been a"
                        +" system error. Please restart the program. ***";
                
                // 0 = rock
                // 1 = paper
                // 2 = scissors
                if (user == 0) {
                    if (computer != 1){
                        if (computer != 0){
                            return "Win";
                        }
                        return "Tie";
                    }
                    return "Lose";
                } // end first nested for loop logic
                if (user == 1){
                    if (computer != 2){
                        if (computer != 1) {
                            return "Win";
                        }
                        return "Tie";
                    }
                    return "Lose";       
                } // end second nested for loop logic
                if (user == 2){
                    if (computer != 0){
                        if (computer != 2) {
                            return "Win";
                        }
                        return "Tie";
                    }
                    return "Lose";       
                } // end third nested for loop logic
                return error; // null  -- Needed to return something 
                // -- better practice teacher?
            } // end class Game ~ End Calculate Game & Return     
    } // end class RPS

```
````

Answer (score 10):

### Code formatting

You have some formatting and indentation problems. Please run your code through a formatter, for example this one

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm

to make it more readable and follow standards.

### Logic

```
while (playAgain = true) {
```

This is wrong, it's supposed to be `==` , not `=` . It works anyway since what you do is just set the `playAgain` variable to `true` in the first run, which is the same value as it already has, and since during the `while` loop it checks the truth value of `playAgain`.

`while(playAgain)` is equivalent to `while(playAgain == true)`

### Comments

```
    } // end while 
} // end switch
```

These comments are in the wrong order. The `switch` is inside the `while` , so it ends first. But you should not need these comments at all. If you use a good code editor and proper indentation, you will easily see (and get auto-highlight) on which bracket matches which. I suggest using an editor such as IntelliJ or Visual studio code.

### Logic 2

The win/lose/tie code is very long and messy.

First, for ties you can just check

```
if (user == computer) {
    return "Tie";
}
```

That covers all combinations that create a tie. With those cases out of the way, the remaining logic gets simpler.

Since paper beats rock (1 beats 0) and scissors beats paper (2 beats 1), with your convenient number definitions you can then check `user == computer + 1`, but we also need the case for rock beats scissors.

```
if (user == computer + 1 || user == 0 && computer == 2) {
    return "Win";
}
```

Since we have now covered all cases of Tie or Win, any other case will lose

```
else {
    return "Lose";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

### Java naming convention

The method name should always start with a lower case.

- `WelcomeP1` -> `welcomeP1`
- `P1Choice` -> `p1Choice`
- `ComputerChoice` -> `computerChoice`
- `Game` -> `game`

### Use `java.io.PrintStream#printf` instead of `java.io.PrintStream#println` when you have to concatenate

`java.io.PrintStream#printf` offer you to use [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) to build the string without concatenating it manually. The only downside is you will be forced to add the break line character yourself; in java you can use the `%n` to break the line (portable between various platforms) or uses the traditional `\n` / `\r\n`.

**Before**

```java
System.out.print("-------------> You " + game() + "!!!");
```

**After**

```java
System.out.printf("-------------> You %s!!!",  game());
```

---

**Before**

```java
System.out.println("The computer's choice was " + computerPiece + "...");
```

**After**

```java
System.out.printf("The computer's choice was %s...%n", computerPiece); //With a new line
```

### Always use the primitives when possible

When you know that it's impossible to get a null value with the number, try to use the primitives; this can prevent the unboxing of the value in some case.

In your code, you can replace the `Boolean` to `boolean` since you have only the `true` and `false` values.

### Extract some of the logic to methods.

When you have logic that does the same thing, you can generally move it into a method and reuse it.

You can extract some of the logic that asks if the user wants to play Rock, Paper or Scissors into a method and reuses it.

```java
private static String askIfWantToPlay(Scanner scanner) {
   String userPlay = "";
   while (userPlay.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
      System.out.println("Please press y for (Y)es \nor n for (N)o: ");
      userPlay = scanner.next().trim();
   }
   return userPlay;
}
```

This method will remove some duplication.

If you want to, you could centralize the logic of exiting in this new method; check if the user want to exit or not.

```java
private static void askIfWantToPlayAndExitOtherwise(Scanner scanner) {
   String userPlay = "";

   while (!"n".equalsIgnoreCase(userPlay) && !"y".equalsIgnoreCase(userPlay)) {
      System.out.println("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
      System.out.println("Please press y for (Y)es \nor n for (N)o: ");
      userPlay = scanner.next();
   }

   if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(userPlay)) {
      System.exit(0);
   } else {
      System.out.println("*************************************");
      System.out.println("Excellent! Thank you...\nLet's Play!");
   }
}
```

With this method, the code is easier to read and don’t propagate logic everywhere in the application; you can do the same thing with the user choice for the (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors and return only a valid choice.

Answer (score 5):

I can agree with all of in two previous answers, however I have to address the issue of implementation of game logic itself. I just so happens that we understand the game logic of the game because we all know the game, but if we look at the code it is difficult to extract the game logic from the code. It is not written in clean, easy to understand way, especially with deep `if` statement nesting.

```
public static String Game(){
                int user = P1Choice();
                int computer = ComputerChoice();
                String error = "*** If you are reading this, there has been a"
                        +" system error. Please restart the program. ***";
                
                // 0 = rock
                // 1 = paper
                // 2 = scissors
                if (user == 0) {
                    if (computer != 1){
                        if (computer != 0){
                            return "Win";
                        }
                        return "Tie";
                    }
                    return "Lose";
                } // end first nested for loop logic
                if (user == 1){
                    if (computer != 2){
                        if (computer != 1) {
                            return "Win";
                        }
                        return "Tie";
                    }
                    return "Lose";       
                } // end second nested for loop logic
                if (user == 2){
                    if (computer != 0){
                        if (computer != 2) {
                            return "Win";
                        }
                        return "Tie";
                    }
                    return "Lose";       
                } // end third nested for loop logic
                return error; // null  -- Needed to return something 
                // -- better practice teacher?
            } // end class Game ~ End Calculate Game & Return     
    } // end class RPS
```

I found a way to implement this game logic in more clear and easy to read and understand way.

#### Use enumerations

Enumerations can help greatly with code clarity

```
public enum PlayedMove
{
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS;
}
```

They are self-explanatory

```
public enum Winer
{
    DRAW,
    PLAYER,
    COMPUTER;
}
```

#### The new game logic

As if you are explaining it to a man and not a computer

```
public class GameLogic
{
    public static Winer getWiner(PlayedMove player, PlayedMove computer)
    {
        if (player == computer)
        {
            return Winer.DRAW;
        }
        else if (isPlayerWiner(player, computer))
        {
            return Winer.PLAYER;
        }
        else
        {
            return Winer.COMPUTER;
        }
    }
    
    private static boolean isPlayerWiner(PlayedMove player, PlayedMove computer)
    {
        return ((player == PlayedMove.ROCK && computer == PlayedMove.SCISSORS)
             || (player == PlayedMove.SCISSORS && computer == PlayedMove.PAPER)
             || (player == PlayedMove.PAPER && computer == PlayedMove.ROCK));
    }
}
```